# Stop playing ( not pause ) HTML5 video on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

Is there any way we can make a HTML5 video to completely stop a video on mouseout?
By stop I mean resetting the video state, just as refreshing the page. All I could get is having the video on pause on mouseout, but this is not what I want.
Thank you.

jsbin:
https://jsbin.com/fenixinuku/edit?html,css,js,output

HTML:

```
<video class="myvideo" src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" width="auto" height="auto" alt=""></video>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myvideo").on("mouseover", function(event) {
    $(this).get(0).play();

  }).on('mouseout', function(event) {
    $(this).get(0).pause();
  });
})
```

EDIT:
Thank you guys, based on your answers I made an alternative to this by displaying the video poster as the first frame ( Thank you Terence Eden for suggestion).
The only small issue is that the image poster is flickering on mouseout..Any better solution ?

HTML:

```
   <video class="myvideo" src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" width="auto" height="auto" alt="" poster="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3html5.gif"></video>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myvideo").on("mouseover", function(event) {
    $(this).get(0).play();

  }).on('mouseout', function(event) {
    this.load();
  });
})
```

demo 2 jsbin: https://jsbin.com/kivisutici/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Removing the video `src` property and adding it again should work. Try this inside the `mouseout` event:

```
var video = $(this).get(0);
var source = video.src;
video.src = "";
video.src = source;
```

Comment: why force video data re-fetching and unnecessary bandwith if you can set time to 0 and achieve the exact same.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following and let me know if it worked for you. 
// Link here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp

```
$(".myvideo"). mouseout(function() {
    $(this).get(0).currentTime = 0;
});

or 

$(".myvideo"). mouseout(function() {
    $(this).currentTime = 0;
});
```

Comment: currentTime is a jQuery method? also, why you use mouseover instead of mouseleave? Also why suggesting such a bad coding resource?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan javascript functions can be used in conjunction with jQuery functions. Furthermore, I understand and thanks for pointing out that mouseover wouldn't work as it should be mouseout instead. Finally, I provided a link to w3school because they had a working example of what I believed was relevant to the problem. Please feel free to share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things.

First, set the current time to `0`.

```
$(this).get(0).currentTime = 0;
```

That returns the player position to 0 mins, 0 seconds - as though you had refreshed the page.

Secondly, you can set the `poster` for the video. By default this is the first frame of the video - but you can set it to any external JPG that you want.

Comment: Can we use `.prop` instead of exiting unnecessarily with `.get` the jQuery Object? Or why don't you use simply `this.currentTime`?

Comment: Any example on how to use poster properly  please?

Comment: Hi @RokoC.Buljan - I used `.get` to mirror the original code. I thought that was the simplest way to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you `mouseout` to this

```
.on('mouseout', function(event) {
    $(this).get(0).currentTime = 0
    $(this).get(0).pause();
  });
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/worusoragi/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: You could use `$(this).prop({currentTime:0, pause:true})` ?

Answer (score -1):

This is the sample code for stop video, using pause function on mouse-out in HTML5.

```
<script>
function testover(e)
{
//e.src="movie.mp4";
e.play();
}
function testout(ee)
{
ee.pause();
ee.currentTime =0;
//ee.src=null;
}
</script>
<video width="320" height="240" onmouseover="testover(this)" onmouseout="testout(this)" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Please neglect if it is not useful.